# (Primefaces + JSF) can not update binding component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, bind

Please explain to me why: i used:

```
<p:megaMenu id="mngTop" model="#{topprocess.mnModel}"> 
</p:megaMenu>
```

then megaMenu can be updated by other component(from button, other ajax), but i used:

```
<p:megaMenu id="mngTop"> 
<p:submenu label="Trợ giúp" binding="#{myBean.snMenu}"> 
</p:submenu> 
</p:megaMenu>
```

other component can not update (Sorry for my english) :)